# bind_plans and map transformation

Tags: drake-r-package

Is it possible to use a map transformation with a grouping variable that is described in an external plan?

In other words, this works for me:

```r
plan_a = drake_plan(
    foo = target(x + 1, transform = map(x = c(4, 5, 6))),
    bar = target(y + 5, transform = map(foo))
)
```

but this doesn't:

```r
plan_a = drake_plan(
    foo = target(x + 1, transform = map(x = c(4, 5, 6))),
)
plan_b = drake_plan(
    bar = target(y + 5, transform = map(foo))
)
bind_plans(plan_a, plan_b)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using the `transform_plan` function.

Comment: Yup, that's how I recommend doing it.